# asp.net windows authentication several paths in one location

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

I am using the windows authentication to control the users that are visiting specific sites in our intranet. I have several pages that are only allowed to be seen by some, but always the same people. can I put several paths in one locations, somewhat along those lines?

```
  <location path="Default.aspx, site1.aspx, site2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="someUsers"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

thanks in advance

### Edit:

I want to avoid going like this:

```
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="someUsers"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="site1.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="someUsers"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="site2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <allow users="someUsers"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the configuration in web config as below:

```
  <location path="Default.aspx, site1.aspx, site2.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="User1,User2"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This is allow only user1 and user2 access to the specific pages while denying access to all others. Hope this helps.

The following link [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config) may be helpful for setting the authorization rules.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing or the errors you are encountering in above implementation? Maybe, you are missing something else.

Comment: I want to give the permissions to acces several pages to the same persons. instead of opening a new `<location>` tag each time I thought there might be a way to use the same permission guidelines for several pages in one go. see my edit.